# Devise: How to customize reset password token?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-api, forgot-password

Need to create 6 digits reset password token.

Everyone is sharing following code, but none has explained how.

```
def set_reset_password_token
  raw, enc = Devise.token_generator.generate(self.class, :reset_password_token)

  self.reset_password_token   = enc
  self.reset_password_sent_at = Time.now.utc
  save(validate: false)
  raw
end
```

I need 6 digit code, with no redirect URL in email template.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to set the password rather than generating a token. What this code does is it sets the token which is then used to create the reset password link. What you can do is to skip devise and create a form where you can get a email and then in your controller you do something like

```
user.password = 'new password'
user.password_confirmation = 'new password'
user.save
```

and then send this password through mail using action-mailer